# Render or evaluate dynamic tag string

Tags: react-native

I'm looking to store some content in the backend which contains a mix of tag components with styles. When the following renders, I just get '<Text style={{color:"#f00"}}>Hello World' as the output rather than 'Hello World'.

```
let fromDb = '<Text style={{color:"#f00"}}>Hello World</Text>';
return (
   {fromDb}
)
```

How can I render or evaluate the tag string as code?

Comment: Instead of storing the Text component in the db, store the text and style.

Comment: Forgot to mention this is react-native.

Comment: The fromDB variable can contain a mix of react native tags, so I can't split them and parameterise them.

Comment: So answering my own question... Obviously not an ideal answer, but it is an answer for anyone who really needs it, but discovered I can do eval(<Text style={{color: '#f00'}}>Hellow World</Text>);

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
let fromDb = '<Text style={{color:"#f00"}}>Hello World</Text>';

return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {fromDb}             
        </View>
    )
```

Comment: Didn't help, somehow I need to evaluate/execute the string as react native tags.

Comment: You can render view as per your condition as you want like ( return isTrue ? <Text style={{color:"#f00"}}>Hello World</Text> : null )